# strategy for integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I don't want too much of a hint, so won't display my particular example.

Given an unbounded function $\phi$. I want to compute its Lebesgue integral over $(a,b)$. It blows up to infinity at $b$ but is defined elsewhere. Being unbounded it is not Riemann integrable. The integral converges. The function is monotone increasing. I want a sequence of bounded functions that converge to $\phi$. Would $\phi_n$ the restriction of $\phi$ to $(a,b-\frac{1}{n})$ be a good choice, or does the domain of the functions in the sequence have to be $(a,b)$ if I want to use standard convergence theorems (such as dominated, monotone convergence etc)?

Comment: "Being unbounded it is not Riemann integrable" Why?

Comment: that's by definition. it's not defined on [a,b], so it cannot be riemann integrable over (a,b)

Comment: You could still compute it using the improper Riemann integral if possible. Right?

Comment: yes. my book doesn't define riemann integrability for unbounded functions. thus im avoiding the fact that if the improper integral converges it will be the same as the lebesgue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and use $$\phi_n = \begin{cases}\phi & (a,b-1/n)\\ 0 & [b-1/n,b) \end{cases} = \phi \cdot \chi_{(a,b-1/n)}$$

Comment: is that the same as introducing a characteristic function?

Comment: @cap Yes. ${}{}$

Comment: @cap 
You may be interested in this example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222485/compute-lim-n-to-infty-int-0n-left1-fracx2n-rightne-x-dx/222490#222490

though here $b$ is $\infty$ and hence the corresponding sequence is $$f_n(x) = \left(1 + \dfrac{x}{2n} \right)^n e^{-x} \chi_{[0,n]} = \begin{cases} \left(1 + \dfrac{x}{2n} \right)^n e^{-x} & x \in [0,n]\\ 0 & x > n\end{cases}$$